# How to Extract an MFCC using C#

Tags: c#

I'm doing a personal project which requires me to do some signal processing and feature extraction in C#, more specifically extracting [MFCCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum), is there any available code for calculating MFCCs in C# ?

Also if there's anything well-written for other languages (Objective-C, C, C++, or even Java), I think I'll be able to get the idea and rewrite it in C#.

Comment: I was curious to know if you got around to porting code to c#. I am looking for something similar and would be happy to collaborate if possible.

Comment: The MFCC algorithm is explained in great details here: http://www.practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/

Comment: I found an implementation in Python: https://github.com/embatbr/tg/blob/master/src/features.py It basically confirms algorithm I mentioned in my previous comment. It also shows DCT applied to energies, which is not described in the algorithm breakdown from the previous post. DCT is just mentioned there but the implementation details are missing.

Answer (score 5):

There is a great tutorial of how to get MFCC (easy to implement in C#):
[Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficient (MFCC) tutorial](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/)

(I know the thread is years old, but maybe future readers will use the answer...)

Comment: The DSP.cs code file has now moved to: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/images/1/1f/Dsp.zip?20130912055231

Comment: The code mentioned in the answer is buggy, undocumented and worth looking only if you need to create your own one from scratch.

Comment: Well, that's what I needed, @zmechanic :). They changed the version of the code from the one that I used back then, which is not even available anymore. Maybe this is why, even though you say that it's buggy, I remember it was of real help for me. Thank you for your input though... maybe I should remove the reference to the code not to mislead people?

Comment: I found where the bug is in that implementation. It has the last part of algorithm, DCT (discrete cosine transformation), being implemented incorrectly. As a result every other MFCC bucket was empty. The rest of the code is fine. I implemented DCT Type II from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html, and everything seems to be in the right place now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling ambitious there is a Java implementation [in CoMirva](http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/Research/Development/CoMIRVA/releases/0.08c/CoMIRVA/doc/comirva/audio/util/MFCC.html).  Complexity of porting to C# is unknown - could be not too bad, depending on the match between features used in that and what's in .Net Fwk.

My guess is that the major complexity is not in porting this class, but in making sure you also have code to generate correct inputs to it.

> public class MFCC
>
> extends
> java.lang.Object
>
> **Mel Frequency
> Cepstrum Coefficients - MFCCs**
>
> **Description:**
>
> Computes the MFCC representation of a
> pcm signal. The signal is cut into
> short overlapping frames, and for each
> frame, a feature vector is is
> computed, which consists of Mel
> Frequency Cepstrum Coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I dont think generating the input would be much of an issue... it will be importing some wav files and dividing them into 1s frames, and applying MFCC algorithms to them. this is the way its normally done in MATLAB.

Comment: @Sarah - OK, hope you find something that works for you anyway.